# formula function in vba

Tags: excel, vba

how can i transfer this formula in vba  =IF(F2<2749,"80",LOOKUP(F2,DataUser!K2:M38))

Comment: Try and record a macro?

Comment: using microsoft visual basic for application

Comment: How would you like the VBA code to return the result?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
    If Range("F2").Value < 2749 Then
        Debug.Print 80
    Else
        Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Lookup(Range("A2"), Worksheets("DataUser").Range("K2:M38"))
    End If
```

Comment: @Dyim: Glad I could help! But we here, if somebody supplies a solution to solve our question, tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**... Of course, this is done only if the code answers your question. I already received a vote down after I posted only the `Lookup` part and had something urgent to finish... :)